# How can I set React Native Video to send or not send credentials, i.e. cookies, on each petition?

Tags: react-native, fetch, react-native-video

I need to avoid sending cookies from my react native video implementation, but can't change the credentials behavior:

```
import Video from 'react-native-video';
...

const App = () => {
...

  return (
    <View>
      <Video
        source={{
          uri: url,
          type: 'm3u8',
          credentials={false}
          ...
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

I'm still getting the Cookie header on server...

Comment: Is this spelled `whithCredentials`?

Comment: I couldn't find useful documentation about it. I tried with different expresiones, like credentials, with same result. I opted here by whithCredentials because it was useful in other libraries for web, like videojs.

Comment: `whithCredentials` or `withCredentials`???????

Comment: Even spelled correctly, this component does not have this prop, so not sure what you're on about.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, and sorry for my typo. The point is: ¿how can I set the library to send or not send credentials, i.e. cookies, on each petition?